# How to convert a GMT timestamp to Unix timestamp (javascript)

Tags: javascript, timestamp

I'm parsing an rss feed and each entry has a timestamp such as this: 2009-09-21T21:24:43+04:00
Is there any way to convert this date format to a unix timestamp with javascript?

I just want to be able to record the latest rss entry date, but I need to standardize the time to GMT time or Unix timestamp to do this.

Comment: @makee - I skipped over that detail, sorry for that.

Comment: @makee - this is a quibble, but the is an ISO-8601 timestamp (or an XML 'dateTime' value) not a "GMT timestamp".  Indeed, the timestamp says that timezone is 4:00hrs ahead of UTC/GMT.

Comment: @makee - this is a quibble, but the string that you gave as an example is an ISO-8601 timestamp (or maybe an XML Schema 'dateTime' value) not a "GMT timestamp". Indeed, the timestamp says that timezone is 4:00hrs ahead of UTC/GMT.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The format appears to be ISO-8601. Assuming that is true, [this blog](http://delete.me.uk/2005/03/iso8601.html) provides a javascript solution to this.

Comment: Apparently, that solution contains at least one bug, possibly two.

Answer (score 0):

As I met the same problem, the solution involving [Google Closure Library](http://closure-library.googlecode.com/svn/docs/class_goog_i18n_DateTimeParse.html) would be:

```
var pattern = "yyyy-MM-ddTHH:mm:ssZZZZZ";
parser = goog.i18n.DateTimeParse(pattern);
var d = new Date();
parser.parse("2009-09-21T21:24:43+04:00", d);
unixTime = d.getTime();
```