# Converting Date and Time To Unix Timestamp

Tags: javascript, regex, unix, timestamp

I'm displaying the date and time like this

> 24-Nov-2009 17:57:35

I'd like to convert it to a unix timestamp so I can manipulate it easily. I'd need to use regex to match each part of the string then work out the unix timestamp from that.

I'm awful with regex but I came up with this. Please suggest improvements ^.^

```
/((\d){2}+)-((Jan|Feb|Mar|Apr|May|Jun|Jul|Aug|Sep|Oct|Nov|Dec)+)-((\d){4}+) ((\d){2}+):((\d){2}+):((\d){2}+)/gi
```

How can I do this?

Comment: Complete side comment, but everytime I see your name I think "Ben Shalock Lock Ben" (Ref: http://www.discogs.com/House-Of-Pain-Shamrocks-And-Shenanigans-Boom-Shalock-Lock-Boom/release/229941 :)

Comment: My evil twin brother, we don't talk about him.

Comment: Duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1457607/how-to-convert-a-gmt-timestamp-to-unix-timestamp-javascript

and here

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1416296/parsing-a-date-in-long-format-from-atom-feed

Comment: You can remove the '+' on the regex groupings.  That means "1 or more times" and you only want the group to match one time.

Answer (score 93, accepted):

If you just need a good date-parsing function, I would look at [date.js](http://www.datejs.com/). It will take just about any date string you can throw at it, and return you a JavaScript Date object.

Once you have a Date object, you can call its getTime() method, which will give you milliseconds since January 1, 1970. Just divide that result by 1000 to get the unix timestamp value.

In code, just include date.js, then:

```
var unixtime = Date.parse("24-Nov-2009 17:57:35").getTime()/1000
```

Comment: You don't even need the library to parse that format, do you?

Comment: It's worth noting that without date.js, Date.parse will take a string and return a unix timestamp.  But it's very strict about the format.  In the OP's example, you would need to string.replace('-', '/').  Other than that, I'm pretty sure it would work in all modern browsers.

I agree that date.js is much more reliable though.

Comment: stick to your regexp.  A localized javascript library is overkill if you are using a fixed date format.  If you have control over this format, you should consider using something more neutral and easier to parse, like ISO8601.

Comment: @Marco: I didn't even bother trying the native <code>Date.parse</code> method -- That exact format works in Chrome, but returns NaN in Firefox (it works with "/" in both, though)

Comment: Ahh - I only tested in Chrome.. that explains my confusion!

Comment: `Date.parse("24-Nov-2009 17:57:35").getTime` isn't a function. All you need is `Date.parse("24-Nov-2009 17:57:35")/1000`. Why did this get so many upvotes when its the WRONG answer?

Comment: Date.parse() isn't entirely bulletproof. Here's some info on cross-browser Date.parse() behavior: http://dygraphs.com/date-formats.html. In my case, I learned the hard way that a date time string in the form of "2016-08-09 05:00 PM" will yield NaN in Firefox 47.

Comment: That's why the answer is actually recommending *not* using the browser's Date.parse(), but rather using date.js, which provides a more robust alternative.

Answer (score 67):

Seems like `getTime` is not function on above answer.

```
Date.parse(currentDate)/1000
```

Comment: I just copied Date.parse('19-04-2015 18:31:00')/1000 this in browser console and it gives NaN can you give solution @chovy

Comment: I'm guessing your date is not correct formatted. You can also use moment(datestring).unix()

Comment: date is in dd-mm-yy H:i:s format. Am i doing wrong?

Comment: `var unixtime = (new Date).getTime()/1000;`  http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_gettime.asp

Comment: Please note that in Chrome it may not be correct: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7964922/jquery-date-parse-returning-nan-in-chrome-browser

Answer (score 7):

You can use [`Date.getTime()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/getTime) function, or the `Date` object itself which when divided returns the time in milliseconds.

```
var d = new Date();

d/1000
> 1510329641.84

d.getTime()/1000
> 1510329641.84
```

Answer (score 0):

Using a date picker to get date and a time picker I get two variables, this is how I put them together in unixtime format and then pull them out...

```
let datetime = oDdate+' '+oDtime;
let unixtime = Date.parse(datetime)/1000;
console.log('unixtime:',unixtime);
```

to prove it:

```
let milliseconds = unixtime * 1000;
dateObject = new Date(milliseconds);
console.log('dateObject:',dateObject);
```

enjoy!