# How to convert javascript to json date?

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, date, datetime

How can i convert the javascript date to Json date format,

> > let see the same example here
> >
> > my json date format = **1388923658000**
> >
> > Javascript date format =**Sun Jan 05 2014 15:07:38 GMT+0300 (Arab Standard Time)**
> >
> > Now my question is, if i pass the current date means i need to return in json date format..

can you help me to solve this issue

Comment: Possible duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1791895/converting-date-and-time-to-unix-timestamp

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your JSON date looks like *the number of milliseconds since 1 January 1970 00:00:00 UTC*. The Date constructor happily accepts this:

```
var d = new Date(1388923658000);
console.log(d); // Sun Jan 05 2014 17:07:38 GMT+0500
```

If want it the other way round you need to:

```
var d = new Date();
console.log(d.getTime()); // 1391578510977
```

Comment: he means the other way round - Javascript to JSON date