# Converting a String Date to a Unix Timestamp in Javascript

Tags: javascript, parsing

How can I parse a date such as the following and convert it to a Unix timestamp using JavaScript?

```
Sat Mar 29 2014 16:10:00 GMT+0800 (Taipei Standard Time)
```

Thanks.

Comment: new Date("Sat Mar 29 2014 16:10:00 GMT+0800 (Taipei Standard Time)").getTime()/1000; with a result of 1396195200 which is not a correct date.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Converting Date and Time To Unix Timestamp](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1791895/converting-date-and-time-to-unix-timestamp)

Answer (score -3, accepted):

you just need a good date-parsing function, I would look at date.js . It will take just about any date string you can throw at it, and return you a JavaScript Date object.
Once you have a Date object, you can call its getTime()
method, which will give you milliseconds since January 1, 1970. Just divide that result by 1000 to get the unix
timestamp value.
In code, just include date.js, then:
`var unixtime = Date.parse("24-Nov-2009 17:57:35")
.getTime()/1000`

Get date.js from http://www.datejs.com/

More here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/1792009/390897

Comment: Copied and pasted from [http://stackoverflow.com/a/1792009/390897](http://stackoverflow.com/a/1792009/390897)...

Comment: Yes? Cause I attempted to help and you want the vote and you didn't see the reference link? Pathetic

Comment: using datejs, i recieved error: TypeError: Date.parse(...) is null
var unixtime = Date.parse(ev["start_date"]).getTime()/1000 which ev["start_date"] is equal to "Sat Mar 29 2014 16:10:00 GMT+0800 (Taipei Standard Time)"

Comment: DateJS will not understand the last portion of your string "(Taipei Standard Time)", so you'll need to remove that with some regex or use a different library (e.g. moment.js) that can handle such strings.