# using date.js to combine date, time and convert to unix timestamp in javascript

Tags: javascript, datetime, unix-timestamp

I have two values

```
var date = "2012-08-10";
var time = "10:10";
```

Then I do

```
var dte = date + " " + time;
```

and

```
var dte = new Date(dte).getTime() / 1000;
```

The below link says it needs date.js to give right reults 
    [Converting Date and Time To Unix Timestamp](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1791895/converting-date-and-time-to-unix-timestamp)

Can the above code give right results without date.js

Comment: its gives NaN if date is in format 2012-08-10 but works if format is 2012.08.10 But this is another issue..

Comment: whats is your `dateformat` and what your required output ?

Comment: date and time is string and i need output in unix timestamp