# Jsonata module usage in NodeJS Project

Tags: javascript

I have tried jsonata exerciser. It looks cool.

But I have to implement it in my code(NodeJS).

Let's say

Input is:

```js
{
  "id": "course_uuid1",
  "description": "Sample course description",
  "contentType": "COURSE",
  "category": "Course",
  "durationInSeconds": 500,
  "expertiseLevels": ["INTERMEDIATE"],
  "imageUrl": "https://percipio.com/courseuuid1/imagelink",
  "link": "https://percipio.com/courseuuid1",
  "modalities": ["LISTEN", "READ", "WATCH"],
  "languageCode": "en",
  "parent": null,
  "publishDate": "2018-11-19T10:23:34Z",
  "sourceName": null,
  "technologyTitle": null,
  "technologyVersion": null,
  "title": "Java",
  "by": ["admin"]
}
```

Transformation logic is:

```js
{
  "pkID": id,
  "description": description,
  "componentTypeID": contentType,
  "totalLength": durationInSeconds,
  "thumbnailURI": imageUrl,
  "locale": languageCode,
  "createTimestamp": publishDate,
  "title": title,
  "lastUpdateUser": by
}
```

I want output in the transformation logic format, but through NODEJS code.

Please suggest

Comment: And your problem is? What have you tried? This seems to be simple object mapping

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Install **jsonata** node module and try below code:

```
var jsonata = require('jsonata');
    let input=
    {
      "id": "course_uuid1",
      "description": "Sample course description",
      "contentType": "COURSE",
      "category": "Course",
      "durationInSeconds": 500,
      "expertiseLevels": ["INTERMEDIATE"],
      "imageUrl": "https://percipio.com/courseuuid1/imagelink",
      "link": "https://percipio.com/courseuuid1",
      "modalities": ["LISTEN", "READ", "WATCH"],
      "languageCode": "en",
      "parent": null,
      "publishDate": "2018-11-19T10:23:34Z",
      "sourceName": null,
      "technologyTitle": null,
      "technologyVersion": null,
      "title": "Java",
      "by": ["admin"]
    }
    let exp="{'pkID': id,'description': description,'componentTypeID': contentType,'totalLength': durationInSeconds,'thumbnailURI': imageUrl,'locale': languageCode,'createTimestamp': publishDate,'title': title,'lastUpdateUser': by}";
    let expression = jsonata(exp);
    let expResult = expression.evaluate(input);
    console.log(expResult);
```

Comment: One more thing, i want to do transform publishDate(input) in unix time stamp.How can i achieve the same through this code.

Comment: @Nimmo you can convert the date and use that in the expression. 
below link may help you to convert date to UNIX timestamp https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1791895/converting-date-and-time-to-unix-timestamp

Answer (score 1):

I think this is what you want:

```
var inputJson={
  "id": "course_uuid1",
  "description": "Sample course description",
  "contentType": "COURSE",
  "category": "Course",
  "durationInSeconds": 500,
  "expertiseLevels": ["INTERMEDIATE"],
  "imageUrl": "https://percipio.com/courseuuid1/imagelink",
  "link": "https://percipio.com/courseuuid1",
  "modalities": ["LISTEN", "READ", "WATCH"],
  "languageCode": "en",
  "parent": null,
  "publishDate": "2018-11-19T10:23:34Z",
  "sourceName": null,
  "technologyTitle": null,
  "technologyVersion": null,
  "title": "Java",
  "by": ["admin"]
};

var outputJson={
  "pkID": inputJson.id,
  "description": inputJson.description,
  "componentTypeID": inputJson.contentType,
  "totalLength": inputJson.durationInSeconds,
  "thumbnailURI": inputJson.imageUrl,
  "locale": inputJson.languageCode,
  "createTimestamp": inputJson.publishDate,
  "title": inputJson.title,
  "lastUpdateUser": inputJson.by
}
```